# What is the difference between Reader and Parser?

Tags: haskell

I would like to know, what is the difference between Reader and Parser?

For example, I have the following text:

```
pcp-action: MESSAGE
pcp-body-type: text
field1:value1
field2:value2


this is the body!
```

The double spaces separate head and body. At the end, I would like to have a head and a body datatype to keep them.

The question is, should I use the Parser or the Reader?

Comment: What are Reader and Parser? By default, when you say Reader you mean monad Reader which doesn't have relation to text reading.

Comment: @WillNess I changed it. Reader does not mean for reading the text? In my case, which one would be the right choice?

Comment: "have the following text" where do you have it?

Comment: @WillNess The text is below. Can you see it? Or I did something wrong.

Comment: is it in an external file? in your source code file? where?

Comment: Ah sorry. I will receive the text via websocket.

Comment: "*What is the difference between Reader and Parser?*" What do they have in common?

Comment: can you copy a relevant fragment of your code?

Comment: At moment, I do not have any code. I just want to know, how to proceed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably should be looking for some kind of parser. That is the modern name for a program which does some kind of understanding of text like this.

Sometimes the word reader is used because:

- Parser is used to refer to something else
- it is only tokenising (but such a program is normally called a lexer)
- In lisp, the function which parses strings into objects is called the reader
- In Haskell the typeclass `Read` is implemented to specify how to parse your type from a string
- the words have similar meanings and reader is a much simpler, more common natural language word to think of for this task.

Comment: I am confuse about, when to use `Reader` and when `Parser`.

Comment: You need to write a parser. Parser is an English word for a thing which does parsing and you need a thing that does parsing. Reader is a different English word which sometimes describes a thing which does parsing. If you are thinking of specific things in Haskell you will need to be more specific.

Comment: What is the Reader?

Comment: In which situation should I use Reader? I can also use Reader to parse something, but it is the violation.

Comment: `Reader` simply provides a common, read-only environment to a group of function calls. It has little or no relationship to parsing.

Comment: Aha. Ok I've got it. Thanks a lot.